# VBA code to delete rows based on cell value that update dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where i need to delete rows based on *index* value of a column which output of formula.

This is the data im working on:

[image]

Here's what the data has:

Each Job ID (Column A) has 2 values: True and False assigned to different owners

Now the column F has data that is specified to satisfy certain conditions

Each time a job ID is deleted (both rows of the job), the last values in F column keep updating to "Yes/No" based on the condition

What im trying to achieve:

- To check the rows one at a time and shift/delete two rows (a job) to the bottom when the last column has the value "No"
- The data updates in the last column as these deletions or shifts happen
- So the macro should be dynamic

Here's the code i've tried:

```
Sub delete()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("F" & i).Value = "No" And Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value Then
            Rows(i & ":" & (i + 1)).Cut
            Range("A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This doesn't seem to work. Deletion part has worked partially where i've used the following lines of code:

```
 Rows(i & ":" & (i+1)).Select
        Selection.delete Shift:=x1Up
```

Comment: This may not solve your issue, but your `i` variable and `LastRow` variable should be `Long` instead of an `Integer` if you are going to use it as a row number.

Comment: Another thing: when you program a function that deletes entries, you should go from last to first, not first to last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to offend but I don't see the benefits of your system. Please consider this instead.

1. Create a helper column and enter this formula in row 2 of it.`=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-MOD(ROW(),2),5)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()+1-MOD(ROW(),2),5)))*(IF(AND(INDIRECT(J2)>50,INDIRECT(K2)>50),2,1))+(ROW()/10000)`
2. Copy down to the end of your sheet.
3. Sort on this column.
4. Hide the helper.

Note that the formula is designed to evaluate two consecutive rows of which the first is in a row with an even number, the second having an uneven number. If your row 2 is used for something else the formula needs to be tweaked to start in row 3 or tweaked differently to start in row 4.

And this is how it works.
It adds the two repetitions (column E). If both of them are above 50 it will multiply the result by two. This will ensure that all rows with two valuations above 50 will be sorted above all others. Finally, the row number / 10000 is added. If you have more than 10000 rows in your data make this number 100,000. The point is that the result of this division must always be less than 1 so as not to interfere with the valuations. This addition will work as a tiebreaker when the other valuations are identical and it will ensure that the sequence of your two rows will remain the same after sorting.

Of course, this sort will create a list that is much more sensitive than simply moving worse performers to the end. It will also leave your formula in column F undisturbed.
It's final advantage is that the criteria in the helper column can be fine tuned to even better serve your purposes.